# Python lambda function "translation" causes recursion error

Tags: python, lambda

While attempting to understand python lambda functions, I "translated" this function:

```
s = lambda y: y ** y; s(3)
```

Into this regular, defined function:

```
def power_of_self(y):
    return y ** y
power_of_self(3)
```

When I tried running it as a script (`python lambda_stuff.py`) I had no problem. However, when attempting to run it via the Python shell, this weird thing happened:

```
>>> def power_of_self(y):
...     return y ** y
... power_of_self(3)
File "<stdin>", line 3
power_of_self(3)
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> print power_of_self(3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "<stdin>", line 1, in power_of_self
File "<stdin>", line 1, in power_of_self
File "<stdin>", line 1, in power_of_self
File "<stdin>", line 1, in power_of_self
**A FEW HUNDRED MORE OF THESE**
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

Why did my script execution differ from my shell execution? I wonder if the `...` had anything to do with it.

Comment: That shouldn't have happened; you should have gotten a SyntaxError due to a missing empty line to terminate the function. Have you edited this interpreter session transcript in any way?

Comment: Here's a [snapshot of the shell.](https://s11.postimg.org/6ld2wcu4z/Tom_Python_99_53.png)

Comment: Wait, you *did* get a SyntaxError, and then you kept going and tried to use the function anyway. You're picking up an earlier version of the function with a different bug in it.

Comment: Let's go back a notch, then. Look at J Earls answer below - how is that different from what I did? And why does it throw a SyntaxError?

Comment: In interactive mode, you need a blank line at the end of any top-level block statement (roughly speaking, anything where the prompt changes to `...` instead of `>>>`).

Comment: OK I just got it. Missed the blank line there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `...` means the python shell was waiting for more statements as part of the function.  You need a blank line to end the function when entering an indented block from directly into the python shell.

```
>>> def power_of_self(y):
...     return y ** y
...
>>> power_of_self(3)
27
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function is still been defined in the shell. Hit an extra <kbd>Enter</kbd> before calling the function.